# How can I remove a given number of elements from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist

I have a JLabel array that starts with an integer number of elements. How can I remove an certain number of elements from the array? For example, every time the int is updated:

```
int i = 21;
i = i - removedElements
```

How can I update the array to contain that many elements, instead of creating an entirely new array with the desired number of elements?

Comment: Why is this an array in the first place and not a list?

Comment: Use an `ArrayList`

Comment: You cannot. Java array are fixed-size. Only way is to create a new array of the new size and copy the values you want to keep. *Or* use an `ArrayList`, as @pvg said, since an `ArrayList` will resize automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, List is the way to go here since it is specifically designed for adding and or deleting elements.

However if you would prefer to use the JLabel Array you already have in established then you will need to realize that the only way to delete an element from that array is to actually create another array with the desired element to delete excluded from it then return it into the original array. Below I have supplied a simple method named **deleteJLabelFromArray()** that can do this for you:

```
public static JLabel[] deleteJLabelFromArray(JLabel[] srcArray, int... indexesToDelete) {
    int counter = 0;
    JLabel[] newArray = new JLabel[srcArray.length - indexesToDelete.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < srcArray.length; i++) {
        boolean noGo = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < indexesToDelete.length; j++) {
            if (i == indexesToDelete[j]) { noGo = true; break; }
        }
        if (noGo == false) { newArray[counter] = srcArray[i]; counter++; }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

With this method you can delete whatever indexes you supply within the **indexesToDelete** argument (delimited with a comma). Copy/Paste the code into your project then you can use it something like this:

```
JLabel[] jla = {jLabel2,jLabel3,jLabel4,jLabel5};
jla = deleteJLabelFromArray(jla, 2);
for (int i = 0; i < jla.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(jla[i]);
}
```

In this example we are going to delete the element number 2 (remember that arrays are 0 based) and therefore **jLabel4** would be removed from the Array.

Keep in mind that this would be scary stuff with really big arrays.
Hope this helps.